# Graphs are not rendering in Rstudio using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create Graphs using ggplot2 but it is not rendering eveen though there are no errors thrown.

The R version am using is 3.6.1

```
airquality <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]

p <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Ozone,Temp))+
  geom_point(color = "steelblue", size = 3, alpha = 0.5)+
  facet_grid(.~Month)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

The plot area is blank when I run the code

Answer (score 3):

you are assigning the plot to `p`. either remove the assignment (`p <-`) or add a print statement `print(p)`.